# Can you substitute a variable in a derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a simple derivative that is $dP/dx = v* g$ and $P = K * v^2$ am I allowed to substitute into the derivative and get $d(K*v^2)/dx$? If so, is there a rule or something for this?

Comment: You can, but you need to use product rule to expand it out.

Comment: The chain rule says $\frac {dP}{dx} = \frac {dP}{dv}\frac {dv}{dx}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a rule, it is the product rule for differentiation.

#### It states:-

$\frac{d}{dx}(fg)=g\frac{df}{dx}+f\frac{dg}{dx}$

So you have $\frac{dP}{dx}=vg$ where $P=Kv^2$

Then, $\frac{dP}{dx}$

$=\frac{d}{dx}(Kv^2)$

$=v^2\frac{dK}{dx}+K\frac{dv^2}{dx}$